# Problem using catkin_make in ROS with windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10, ros

I have installed ros Noetic on Windows 10. When I do catkin_make I get cmake errors requiring Ninja. Although I am using Visual Studio 2017 Command prompt, I still get the cmake errors about compiler not found. I can run roscore from the command prompt but catkin_make doesn't work. Why is that?

Running command: "cmake G:\ros_ws\src -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=G:\ros_ws\devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=G:\ros_ws\install -G Ninja" in "G:\ros_ws\build"

CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja". CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set. You probably need to select a different build tool. CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "G:/ros_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". Invoking "cmake" failed

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the "root cause" is here, I'm also on Windows 10 with a fresh Noetic and had the same problem.  I also had previous installs of OpenCV and other things that apparently touched CMake.

However, running

```
catkin_make --use-nmake
```

fixed this for me.  It seems like a potential bug in `c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\Lib\site-packages\catkin\builder.py` (on my system) where I found the hidden switches and it could probably be hacked at.